# Remove paragraph above a Word table in a document column with C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, word-automation, word-interop

I work in a **three-column Word document**. I would like to **insert a new table** within a document column **flush** at the top. Unfortunately it is **not possible** for me to insert it without a paragraph. i insert this table after a column *break* (see code). If i replace the column break with many paragraphs, i can place the table at the top. Unfortunately, this method is **not practical** and **not so easy** to **implement programmatically**.

```
Word.Paragraph oPara4;
var oRng = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(@"\EndOfDoc").Range;
oPara4 = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(oRng);
Word.Range rngPara = oPara4.Range;
rngPara.InsertParagraphBefore();
rngPara.Text = "Some Text Before the break";
oPara4.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;
rngPara.InsertParagraphAfter();
rngPara.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);

// Column Break
rngPara.InsertBreak(Word.WdBreakType.wdColumnBreak);
rngPara.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);


// Create new table in new column (after column break)    
oRng = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(@"\EndOfDoc").Range;
Word.Table tableCopy = document.Tables.Add(oRng, 1,1, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

[image]

Comment: Adding a paragraph before (= above the first column) is the easy way to solve the problem that your tables are at equal height on the page.

Comment: Good approach! The problem is that I have tables that break across a column. So the beginning is further down than the break in the new column.

Comment: I added some info with a screenshot of Word and LibreOffice, but I think you found a BUG in Word. (If I understood your problem correctly!)

Answer (score 2):

The reason for what you're seeing is that Word *requires* a paragraph between tables. The paragraph stores important information regarding the table's position on the page (this can be seen in the Word Open XML). Two immediately adjacent tables (no paragraph between them) are automatically merged. This is ***not*** a bug, as suggested elsewhere in this discussion.

You would, therefore, need a paragraph preceding *all* tables at the top of all columns. This paragraph could be formatted with a very small font size and no "space before" or "space after" - I'd create a special style for it.

It would be important to work in this order:

1. Insert the leading paragraph mark, formatted with the ***Normal*** style.
2. Insert the table below it (table formatting works most reliably when the table is created from the Normal style)
3. Apply the style for the preceding paragraph that makes it smaller

This is one of the reasons I, in response to a previous question, suggested a multi-column table across the page, rather than using newspaper columns...

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. as always very helpful! :) how can i place the paragraph for the next table before the break?

Comment: Is there any possibility to find the last paragraph in a document column? maybe i can do it without a column break but with a calculated sum of paragraphs to move the table into the next column.

Comment: @br0ken.pipe Sorry, I wasn't at a machine over the weekend. Find the last para: Search for the column break using `Find` with the Find text being: `^n` then move backwards. The suggestion about a para after the table, at the end of a column, isn't valid (doesn't work) - you already have that.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution: I shift the new table until it has completely reached the new column.
Not very pretty, but it works (prototype):

```
 // Add paragraph before table
var rangeBeforeTable = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(@"\EndOfDoc").Range;
rangeBeforeTable.InsertParagraphAfter();

// Add table
var newTableRange = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(@"\EndOfDoc").Range;
document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(newTableRange);
var newTable = document.Tables.Add(newTableRange, 1, 1, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
newTable.Range.Paste();

// Save coordinates
int leftOriginal, topOriginal, widthOriginal, heightOriginal;
int left, top, width, height;

// Get coordinates from newly created table
word.ActiveWindow.GetPoint(out leftOriginal, out topOriginal, out widthOriginal, out heightOriginal, newTableRange);

while (true)
{
    // Get coordinates from moving table
    word.ActiveWindow.GetPoint(out left, out top, out width, out height, newTableRange);

    if (top < topOriginal)
    break;

    // Add paragraph before new table and move table down
    document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(newTableRange.Previous());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In above question there seems to be a **bug** in Word (tested with Version 2013)
[image: Word2013]

Same document in LibreOffice (version 6.2.4.2)

[image]

The columns 1 and 2 is 1 table which spread across these 2 columns on the page. In the third column a new table is started. In word it seems to be impossible to align the top-position of all tables.

Comment: It's not a bug - it's by design in Word. See my Answer